# Shopify customer login and signup Api in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

i am develoing an app such as Android and IOS for my store in React Native! The UI is almost completed. I also fetch collections and products successfully.  However I do not see any documantations about Customer Login & sign up etc. Please help me in this case. How can i login and signup via API in my app.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Any luck with this? I am looking for a similar solution. It sounds like you are using the Admin API for your collections and products. But this can't be used for customer login unfortunately. Multipass sounds like the closest thing, but it seems to require you maintain your own customer database, once a user is authenticated with your app, you can then obtain a multipass token from the shopify API.